# How to define constants that multiplies with the trigonometric functions

Tags: python, sympy

I have equation `w`, which contains some trig functions multiplied with come constants. how to express this function in python. I am getting an error that says `a1...a4` and `b` are not defined. I know it is not defined, but I am interested in solving for these constants for a given value of b for a set of for conditions on `w`

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np 
import math as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w=a1*sin(b*x)+a2*cos(b*x)+a3*sinh(b*x)+a4*cosh(b*x)
```

Comment: You tagged the question with *symbolic-math*, so I guess this is a task for [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).

Comment: you are saying I have not imported the package sympy?

Comment: Take a look at [`sympy.symbols`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html).

Comment: The code shows import for a lot of packages but does not actually *use* them. Is that the actual code you are running? Did you read up on how to actually use these packages, e.g. ``sympy``'s symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with sympy you need to import the sympy functions and define the symbols first:

```
In [2]: from sympy import sin, cos, sinh, cosh, symbols                                                                                        

In [3]: a1, a2, a3, a4, b = symbols('a1:5, b')                                                                                                 

In [4]: w=a1*sin(b*x)+a2*cos(b*x)+a3*sinh(b*x)+a4*cosh(b*x)                                                                                    

In [5]: w                                                                                                                                      
Out[5]: a₁⋅sin(b⋅x) + a₂⋅cos(b⋅x) + a₃⋅sinh(b⋅x) + a₄⋅cosh(b⋅x)
```

I recommend going through the sympy tutorial:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Where/how is the name `x` defined? Is there some `sympy` magic that automatically injects it into the module globals?

Comment: Ah, I get it: you're using `isympy`, which _does_ predefine `x` (and some other things).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Mark. Yes, I should have included `x = Symbol('x')`. I put the imports in (they aren't needed in isympy) but I forgot the symbol x!